# Possible to hold multiple values within a single TextInput?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, textinput, native-base

Has anyone ever created some TextInput component which can hold multiple values? For example label = 'Fruits' and a single text input allows user to key in "Banana", "Orange" and so on? Probably automatically splitting them using "Return"/"Enter" key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the react-tag-input for this. Demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tag-input-1nelrc)

[NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tag-input)

Installation

`npm install --save react-tag-input`

[image]

There are [lot](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=react%20tags%20input&rlz=1C1GCEU_enIN820IN820&oq=react%20tags%20input&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l4.4127j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to experiment with.

Another good tag input [react-tagsinput](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tagsinput)

[image]

If bootstrap is an option you could use [this](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/)

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for the correct keyword, tagging is exactly what I needed